# 3D Array or a dynamic 2D array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm developing a shogi (shogi is a Japanese variant of chess) application. Once a piece is taken, I want it to move to a separate part of the screen, but not on the board.

I was wondering whether it would be best to a 3D array (one element would store the type, the other would be the location of the piece and the third would store the amount of that piece type);

The other option is a dynamic 2D array, to store the piece type and location, then keep the same types of pieces close together.

Which would be best for an Android application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not really an android-related question  ,but more of a game design question .

anyway ,if it's similar to chess , how about have a 2d array of pieces , each has its own properties : piece type and player owning the piece ?

Comment: I was wondering which would be better to program for the application; which would take up less memory to code.
I have a 2D array for the board; but I'm thinking for an area off the board to display the pieces that have been taken; and if say more than one pawn is taken, I'd like them to be grouped together.

Comment: on chess you can't put more than one piece on a single cell so it's ok for the class of the board to assume it .  about the pieces that were taken , just put them on any type of collection you think is most appropriate  (HashSet,ArrayList,...) . if you wish to record the moves as a history , just make it support more than one piece per move . about memory usage , don't worry, for simple classes it's ok . usually, images and memory leaks are those that cause out-of-memory exceptions on android.